# send input parameter with hyphen to api

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Below the input object send to api

```
var inputArray = {
    ...inputArray,
        data:{
            ...inputArray.data,
            firstName:'',
            secondOne:'',
            Third:'',
            Last-Name:'',               
        }
    }; 




var firstName = response[0].firstName;
    var secondOne = response[0].secondOne;
    var Third = response[0].Third;
    var lastName = response[0].lastName;
```

assign the values to input object

```
inputArray.data.firstName = firstName;
    inputArray.data.secondOne = secondOne;
    inputArray.data.Third = Third;
    inputArray.data.Last-Name = lastName;
```

lastname input object contains `inputArray.data.Last-Name = lastName;` hyphen ,when i try to send like above showing error.how to send hyphen input parameters to api

Comment: In an object literal, quote the key name... `{ "Last-Name": "" }`. When assigning to an object, use square-bracket notation... `inputArray.data["Last-Name"] = lastName`

Comment: @Phil : it is working fine. thanks